Unfocused camera effect, geometrical explanation




I noticed that if I make a photo of a chess board with wrong focus, black squares become small and white takes almost all space. It can be well observed on last photo (Lens position = 2). How to explain this effect with camera/lens geometry? If it's too complex, what will be good books, series of articles to understand this?
Camera is raspberry pi module 3.
EDIT:
paper version is normal


It is just that adding even a small amount of white to black makes it very obviously different. Our eyes have logarithmic intensity sensitivity so that a tiny increase in brightness away from zero looks like a large change eg 1 to 2 and 2 to 4 are doubling the intensity  whilst a small change away from 100% luminosity is barely even distinguishable. Despite that there are 10 zillion shades of not quite white paints on offer! It is very much harder to see a faint black dot on a white background than a faint white dot on a perfect black background.

@MartinBrown I have not fully understood on the first try, but your comment gave me idea to try paper chessboard instead of tablet. And it is absolutely different, now I believe I understand. Looks like in unfocused image one pixel corresponds to some area in real world which is blurred together in one pixel. For paper it looks ok, but for tablet white area is more bright than black so white and black mixed together still looks white.
